# Actualizar versión MariaDB en xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

Recientemente he instalado Xampp en un nuevo directorio en mi pc, pero al intentar instalar el Moodle, este me exige la version 10.6 de MariaDB y actualmente la ultima version de Xampp tiene la 10.4, he actualizado la version a la 1.11, sin embargo, al arrancar el servidor de MySQL, me presentó inconvenientes, he consultado foros e incluso a ChatGPT, una parte intenté solucionar y ahora arranca que fue eliminando estos 03 archivos de la carpeta data. (Ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto ya el servidor de MySQL logró arrancar, sin embargo, al entrar en phpMyAdmin, me encuentro con un letrero rojo por configuracion de almacenamiento, si alguien me puede decir como lo soluciono se lo agradezco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me aparecía antes de eliminar los 03 archivos que muestro en la imagen es este. Retrocedí un poco para mostrar el error.

```
2023-05-24  8:25:32 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.3-MariaDB source revision 0bb31039f54bd6******************** as process ***12
2023-05-24  8:25:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.13
2023-05-24  8:25:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
2023-05-24  8:25:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-05-24  8:25:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-05-24  8:25:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16.000MiB, chunk size = 1.000MiB
2023-05-24  8:25:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=4096 bytes)
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Upgrade after a crash is not supported. The redo log was created with MariaDB 10.4.8. You must start up and shut down MariaDB 10.4 or earlier.
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: SSPI: using principal name 'localhost', mech 'Negotiate'
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2023-05-24  8:25:33 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Estaré atento a sus comentarios y el apoyo muchas gracias.

Comment: No tenías que borrar esos archivos, sino moverlos a la carpeta `mysql`. ¿Podrías restaurarlos en esa carpeta desde la papelera?

Comment: Sip, de hecho los tengo en una carpeta fuera de xampp. Tengo mi carpeta mysql (la nueva version)  y mi carpeta mysql.old (la version que viene con xampp), de esta carpeta "mysql.old" he pasado las carpetas, [backup, data, scripts] y los archivos "*.bat" [mysql_installservice.bat, mysql_uninstallservice.bat]. luego en la carpeta "mysql/bin" copié el archivo "my.ini" de la carpeta anterior. Lo edite y agregué la línea "skip-grant-tables" finalmente, ejecuté el archivo "mysql/bin/mysql_upgrade.exe" pero luego no inicia el servidor, por eso habia sacado los archivos en mención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que PhpMyadmin necesita una base de datos llamada `phpmyadmin` y un usuario `pma`. Por defecto en la instalación de Xampp ya vienen creados, pero si se cambia a un nuevo motor de BBDD, hay que crearlos manualmente.

En el mensaje de error hay una parte que dice:

> Algunas funcionalidades extendidas fueron deshabilitadas, **Averigüe por qué**.

Has clic en ese enlace.
Irá a otra página donde hay otro vínculo que dice algo como:

> **Crear** la base de datos 'phpmyadmin' y configurar el almacenamiento.

Has clic en el enlace y se creará la estructura de tablas.

**[*]** Otra forma es yendo a `Xampp/phpMyAdmin/sql` y ejecutar el contenido de `create_tables.sql`

Ahora falta crear el usuario `pma` para darle control a phpmyadmin:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE USER 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON phpmyadmin.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

---

Aunque estés usando Xampp, no necesariamente tienes que usar la base de datos embebida. Puedes usar otra versión, o incluso otro motor de BBDD.

Desde Xampp detén el servicio de MariaDB, si está iniciado.

Descarga la [versión requerida de MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=mariadb&p=mariadb&r=10.10.4&os=windows&cpu=x86_64&pkg=msi&m=acorn).

Instala la aplicación descargada de MariaDB.
Incluso, para pruebas o dev, hay una versión zip que no hay que instalar, [solo configurar](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-windows-zip-packages) (1). Esta opción es interesante porque se podrían tener múltiples versiones.
**(1) [Nota]** En la versión zip de Windows no encontré `mysqld_install_db.exe`, usar `mysql_install_db.exe` en su lugar.

Arrancas el servicio de MariaDB y listo, ya tienes la BD en la versión que necesitas que puedes acceder desde el mismo phpmyadmin de Xampp. Tendrás que hacer el mismo procedimiento del principio, crear la BD `phpmyadmin` y el usuario `pma`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, en parte me sirvió, yo habia copiado de la carpeta anterior la carpeta correspondiente a la base de datos ```phpmyadmin ```, lo que hice fue eliminar esta carpeta, inicié el servidor y me fui a importar el script sql que se encuentra en `xampp/phpMyAdmin/sql/create_tables.sql`, esto creo de nuevo la base de datos con sus tablas y al ir a la pantalla inicial ya el error habia desaparecido.

Answer (score 0):

no estaba seguro si contestar aqui o en otro sitio, pero dado que era de mi interes estas soluciones decidi hacerlo aqui, os comento mi problema, trato de instalar moodle para un trabajo de instituto, inicialmente tenia el problema que estabais comentando sobre mariadb, me sirvio de ayuda lo que dijisteis para que ya no  me volviera a salir esa revision que pedia moodle. Bien, el caso es que instale mariadb 10.6 desde su instalador, algo que me duplico el mysql dentro de los procesos de windows, resulta que el PID de mysql de xampp corresponde a un proceso mysql ok, pero hay otro proceso mysql y dentro sale mariadb. Si cierro ese proceso en phpmyadmin me sale la version anterior. Aparte de todo esto y posiblemente relacionado, al ejecutar moodle, cambio el idioma, pongo las rutas y a darle siguiente, ya no puede acceder a la pagina con un "no se puede acceder a este sitio" y un mensaje de error de "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET", ya no se que hacer para que siga la instalacion de moodle de manera normal, ¿alguna sugerencia? gracias de ante mano

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ¿Un BOT me dice que la respuesta no es clara?  es lo mas gracioso que he leido desde hace tiempo, si me lo dice un admin, moderador u otra persona ok ya me aclararia en que terminos no esta clara, pero un BOT jajajaja es buenisimo